# Performance Comparison Between Python and C++ in ROS2 for Real-Time Applications

Tags: ros2, python, roscpp

Is there a disadvantage in terms of real-time performance when using Python as opposed to C++ in ROS2? If so, how significant is this disadvantage?

Thank you.

Comment: For any real time  project, c++ is going to win by miles in speed.  Read this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/801671/5658788

Comment: this report https://sbel.wisc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/569/2023/04/TR-2023-03.pdf performed some tests on ROS2 and found python to be ~10X slower when publishing and having ~3X more latency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're gonna hate this answer, but: "it depends", and on what you mean by "real time".

Yes, there's a disadvantage - python is slower than c++ (by a lot), and ros2's support for python is meh, and you have the GIL to contend with, and I don't think ros2's newest zero-copy stuff applies to python. But how much it impacts you depends on your usage.

For instance - are you reading from, and controlling a robot, at 1Khz in a tight loop? Then I bet you'd notice a difference in latency.

Are you doing computer vision at 20hz, and are spending all the time inside pytorch anyway? Then I bet you wouldn't notice a difference in latency.

The only way to know is to profile.